# Storyboard button not known in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, storyboard

I have a main.storyboard with a button from which I need to change the image based on wether the app connects through the home Wifi network or through the cloud to a certain device. I gave the button a tag number.

In viewDidLoad I check the connection and change the image if needed. I do this through

```
let myButton = view.viewWithTag(int) as! UIButton
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: “imageName.png”), for .normal)
```

my viedDidLoad looks like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setHomeMenuButton), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)



    checkSavedHomeyAccessData()                     // get Homey's url data from disk if there are

    if appStageLevel > 0 && firstStartAppFlag  {

        firstStartAppFlag = false
        let flag = checkDataStore()

        if flag == 2 {                              // store is already filled, then get iconViews
            DeviceService.getDevicesNameArray() 
            getIconFiles()
        }

    }

    manageViewBasedAppStageLevel()                    // setup views based on stage 

    let networkName = currentSSID()
    timerMapCapabilitiesUpdate()      
}
```

This functioned very well untill today. I added a new function call to the viewDidLoad function and the app crashes directly after startup, telling me that the line with ‘let myButton = ...’ unexpectedly found nill.

here is what function that is now called from viewDidLoad:

```
func timerMapCapabilitiesUpdate() {

  let mapCapabilityArray = getMapCapabilityArray()

  _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 20, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in  // 1


        if self.currentReachabilityStatus != .notReachable {


            if mapCapabilityArray.count != 0 {

                for capabilityOnMap in mapCapabilityArray {

                    getLiveData2Values(tag : capabilityOnMap.tag)

                } // for deviceOnMap

            } // if mapDeviceArray

        } else {

            if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(6) {
                viewWithTag.isHidden = false
                self.view.bringSubview(toFront: viewWithTag)
                // print("No Internet Connection")
            }

        } // if internet available

    }) // end timer block

} // end timerMapDevicesUpdate
```

This would mean in my humble opinion that the storyboard not has loaded before the viewDidLoad methods are starting. Because if the storyboard was loaded the unwrapping would not yield ‘nill’. Anybody a clue how to solve this?

Comment: You may removed the button from the storyboard or changed it's tag

Comment: Yes that is what I considered also, but unfortunately it was not the cause

Comment: When you say 'added a new function call to viewDidLoad' what did you add or do you mean you are calling viewDidLoad in your code somewhere.  Also if it's coming from a storyboard why not use an IBOutlet instead?

Comment: Please share more code in order to get context

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth - I added a call to a method with a timer function.

Comment: @MauricioChirino - I have added the viewDidLoad code. The last line is the timer code I added. I also added the timer code itself

Comment: First of all thanks for your efforts. Found the issue: from the timer I call the function getLiveData2Values from which I call a method in the viewController to update screen. This seems to make the original viewController unaccessible, hence the 'unexpected found nil while unwrapping'

Comment: That shouldn't happen but if you have solved it fine.  You really need to look into IBOutlets instead of finding a view by it's tag though.

Answer (score 0):

During `viewDidLoad` most of the UI elements are still `nil`. If you move your call to `viewWillAppear` or even `viewDidAppear` you will find that the elements have been initialized and you can modify your `myButton` object.

Because `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` can get called more than once you may need to change your logic a little.

I did a quick Google of "UIViewController lifecycle" and found a few blog posts that go into more detail about what happens for each of the standard steps if you want to learn more. Apple used to have such an article but I can't find it today. However, the "Responding to View Events" and "Handling View Related Notifications" parts of the [documentation for UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) will also give you the basics.

Comment: Thanks Walter for your explanation, will give it a ty and look at the recommended documentation